# Select Authorization Type in postman for laravel/passport tokens

Tags: laravel, postman, laravel-passport

I have laravel 5.5 app with api laravel/passport 4.0 and making test in POSTMAN
which Authorization Type ( https://prnt.sc/z6v4jf ) have I to select ?
OAuth 1 looks like that. Is it ?

Also could you please which fields from database must be inserted in it ?
In POSTMAN I need to fill fields :

- Signature Method

  Consumer Key

  Consumer Secret

  Access Token

  Token Secret

Wih command
php artisan passport:install
2 rows with Client ID and Client Secret were added into oauth_clients table
Values from this table? Or some other data

**MODIFIED :**

In oauth_clients table there is 1 row with

```
id = 1
user_id= null
name = Company name
secret = secret value
```

In oauth_access_tokens there are many rows with

```
id = with unique hash
user_id = ref to users
client_id = 1 (ref to single row in oauth_clients table )
name = Company name
```

In POSTMAN on “ authorization” tab I select OAuth and see : https://prnt.sc/z7i6ot
could you please explaine how this tab must be filled with data from my tables ?

Thanks!

Comment: Here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport I found "OAuth2 server implementation". Looks like that it ?

Comment: Pls look at MODIFIED